# How can I remove the next div of the parent of an element?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function yes(event, yesicon) {

  event.stopPropagation();
  yesicon.closest('button').nextSibling.remove(); //Why doesn't this work???
  yesicon.closest('button').remove(); //This works ok

}
```

```html
<div class="doors_list" id="doors_list">
  <button class="accordion">             
                  <div>
                    <img src="Iconos/arrow_down.png" alt="Expand" class="arrow_icon">
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <img src="Iconos/yes.png" onclick="yes(event,this);" alt="Yes" class="yes_icon">
                  </div>  
                  <div>
                    <p class="door_room">Kitchen</p>
                  </div>              
              </button>
  <div class="panel"> --THIS IS THE ONE I WANT TO DELETE --
    <p>Info on Door 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside doors_list I actually have several buttons of class 'accordion' followed by the div of class 'panel' which is the one I want to delete for each one when the 'yes' icon is clicked.

What I want to do is to remove the next div of the class 'panel' with the "yes" function.

yesicon.closest('button') seems to be working ok but when I want to remove the nextSibling it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As a side note, you cannot have a `div` inside a `button`, it is not allowed by the HTML spec.

Comment: What do you mean? it seems to be working just fine

Comment: It works fine, yes, because browsers are built to try and fix such mistakes but if you check the HTML spec (and you should) you will see that it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `nextElementSibling` as it will, as its name implies, be the next sibling element. `nextSibling` will be whatever node follows, and in your case is going to be a text node: the white space characters between your elements.

```js
function yes(event, yesicon) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  yesicon.closest('button').nextElementSibling.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="doors_list" id="doors_list">
  <button class="accordion">
    <div>
      <img src="Iconos/arrow_down.png" alt="Expand" class="arrow_icon" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="Iconos/yes.png" onclick="yes(event,this);" alt="Yes" class="yes_icon" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="door_room">Kitchen</p>
    </div>
  </button>
  <div class="panel">
    --THIS IS THE ONE I WANT TO DELETE --
    <p>Info on Door 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid HTML and that is the cause of your problem.

Leaving aside the issue that a `<div>` is not allowed inside a `<button>` in the first place…

The content of the button is:

- Start div
- img
- End div
- img
- End div

Since there is no open div for the second end tag to close, error recovery implicitly closes the button, and then the div end tag closes the `doors_list` element.

Consequently: The element you are aiming for is not a sibling of the button, but of its parent.

Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/). Write valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to open the div before your icon

```
</div>
 <img src="Iconos/yes.png" onclick="yes(event,this);" alt="Yes" class="yes_icon">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake I made when I copied my code

Comment: The Node.nextSibling read-only property returns the node immediately following the specified one in its parent's childNodes list, or null if the specified node is the last node in that list. If you console.log(yesicon.closest('button').nextSibling), what does it return?

Comment: Because it looks like it is the last one, so I suppose, it is null, isn't it?